# How to add the functionality of previous and next button using to display single record?

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]I have some records in contact object, Every Record Having link to redirect another detail page. In this detail page i need to add previous and Next buttons, once click the Previous Button i need to show Previous Record of Currect Record similarly same as like that of Next record of Currect Record. Please help me and check below fig.

Comment: This might help you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145653/how-to-add-previous-and-next-buttons-to-pop-window-page-using-visualforce-page/145686#145686

Comment: @Shravan Boddula, This example shows all accounts and edit button options. Could you please give me above scenario related example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something that Salesforce currently has through out of the box, it would take custom code to implement.What you can do is you can add an inline vf page which shows the list of contact and on click of any contact , open a VF page and add the functionality of add and prev in the controller.

You can also look into this below post which might help you

["previous" and "next" button within Accounts](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hW5tAAE)

ps: I never tried it before though

There is an idea though for this.do upvote it

[Next and Prev button on records](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqVhAAK)

Comment: Here Iam showing detail page using output text (like vf page2) of particular contact record when i click the contact record in vf page1. But using the output text ,how to possible to show next record using next button.

Comment: I am adding screenshots. Please check once and let me know.

Comment: In the controller for the page , you need to write a SOQL query to get all the contacts related to that account and then implement the pagination kind of stuff for prev and next functionality. Below is a link for pagination which might help you to implement the prev and next button functionality

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/07/14/visualforce-page-with-pagination/

https://www.minddigital.com/how-to-create-pagination-within-salesforce/

Please mark it as answer if it helped you so others can benefit

Comment: I have created 2 pages. I clicked on record in first page,that particular record will goes to next page(Record detail page). In that page I created next,Previous buttons. when i click on next button, i want to display Next Record of Currect Record. How is it possible ?

Comment: You need to write a SOQL Query to get all the related records.Please share what you have tried and then we can help you where ever needed.

Comment: I am already using SOQL Query and get all contacts in first vf page. And Second VF page showing only one record using like {!Contact.FirstName} only display purpose. This page having buttons like already mention above scenario

Comment: You can use the same Controller for both the VF page and can add the methods on click on next or prev to achieve your functionality.You can also rerender your current detail page on click of next or prev button to refresh with the new detail page

Comment: When i using Previous page controller use soql query records will displayed. But here problem is clicking the particular record is not showing this time ,database first record is showing. but get the original id in the page url. why this problem occured

Comment: Please create a new question and paste your code of what you have tried.We will definitely help you there .

Comment: anybody pls give me some more examples

Comment: Displaing contact records using every record having link in vf page 1. this one completed. And next one, When click on record in vf page1 it will redirect to new tab shown vfpage2 with id same record. this one completed. I click the next button then the next record will not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you can take reference of this code for next and previous buttons using standardset controller

```
public class paginationExp {
public ApexPages.StandardSetController controller {set;get;}
    public List<Opportunity> getOpty(){
        List<Opportunity> opps=(List<Opportunity>) controller.getRecords();
        return opps;
    }
    public paginationExp (){
        List<Opportunity> opps=[select name,amount,stagename from  Opportunity];
        controller=new Apexpages.StandardSetController(opps);
        controller.setPageSize(5);
    }
} 



<apex:page controller="paginationExp">
<apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity">
 <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
 <apex:commandButton value="First" action="{!controller.first}" rendered="{!controller.hasPrevious}" />
 <apex:commandButton value="Prev" action="{!controller.previous}" rendered="{!controller.hasPrevious}" />
 <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!controller.next}" rendered="{! controller.hasNext}" />
 <apex:commandButton value="Last" action="{!controller.last}" rendered="{!controller.hasNext}" />
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opty}" var="a">
 <apex:column value="{!a.name}" />
 <apex:column value="{!a.stageName}" />
 <apex:column value="{!a.amount}" />
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```